# Handling mail verification using dj-rest-auth

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, email-verification, dj-rest-auth

I am able to get a verification email to the newly signed up email account. I also can verify the new email but not directly from the link sent in the email. The reason that is the confirmation link should be called with a **post** method, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_endpoints.html#registration).

My urlpatterns list in *url.py* file has the two elements below:

```
urlpatterns = [
...,
...,
path('registration/', RegisterView.as_view(), name='account_signup'),
re_path(r'^account-confirm-email/', VerifyEmailView.as_view(),
 name='account_email_verification_sent')
]
```

For information I am using Django as backend with a frontend framework.

What I want is for the email verification to redirect to a page in the Frontend and from there send the post request. Is there a way to achieve this ? How to send custom email ? how to have a custom register and confirm email view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the verification link - the **URL** in the email - by overwriting the `get_email_confirmation_url`

Example:

```py
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter

class CustomAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def get_email_confirmation_url(self, request, emailconfirmation):

        """
            Changing the confirmation URL to fit the domain that we are working on
        """

        url = (
            "https://example.com/verify-account/"
            + emailconfirmation.key
        )
        return url
```

Also add the following line the **settings.py** file:

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = "users.views.CustomAccountAdapter"
```

the users is the name of the app in Django that has the *custom Acount adapter* implemented. [Documentation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#custom-redirects) here for more details.

Comment: How about customizing the whole email to an HTML mail ?

Comment: it is doable, but it is a headache. I prefer not to do it.

Comment: The solution works only after adding a line of code in settings.py, could you please approve the edit